# Google Drive Viewer not Showing correct output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

step 1: I Wrote one small code in google app script to create a text file with content "hello world!" in google drive
here is code

```
var output = "hello world!";
Logger.log(output);
var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B3d-i0Md_Xz6flVTbXNhSUtDTnZKckZKZGw4OVJ3M1ZTZDMxWnhhNFhiV3BWdEpZVXdrT3M");
theFolder.createFile("test.txt", output, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
```

the above code generate output("hello world!") correctly with file id "0B3d-i0Md_Xz6NFczYWR5LXBYc0U".

In step 2: i am trying to modify the content of file
here is the code

```
var output = "Stack Overflow!";
var myFileName = DriveApp.getFileById('0B3d-i0Md_Xz6NFczYWR5LXBYc0U');
myFileName.setContent(output);
```

After doing this i view the file "test.txt" in google Drive viewer it show the content of file as "hello world!"(wrong output)  but when i open the file in google doc viewer it shows the correct output i.e "Stack Overflow!"

and also i download the file and saw the correct output "Stack Overflow!".

why google drive viewer show wrong output? can anyone have solution for above the problem ?

Comment: I would report this as an issue.  [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: paste the URLs for "google Drive viewer" and "google doc viewer". Make the file public so we can all see it